# Make Typescript node modules work together

Tags: node.js, typescript

Has anybody got a setup working in which module 1 using typescript is referencing another module 2 also with typescript and both use tsd types such as node.d.ts ?

I have no problem compiling both and using them, as long as i simply require module 2. But as soon as i use import instead, i get into duplicate identifier hell, due to the fact that source files in both modules import e.g. node.d.ts typings from obviously different paths. Classes in both projects use e.g 'streams' or 'lodash' thus both use them in typings and thus use the /// reference syntax. The tsconfig in both projects excludes typings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript has come a long way since this was asked, and it's now much easier. You can link the proper files in `package.json`:

```
{
  "main": "library-commonjs.js",
  "module": "library-es6-module.js",
  "typings": "library-commonjs.d.ts"
}
```

`main` is used by packages using CommonJS and Node.js module resolution. `module` is used by packages supporting ES6 imports. And `typings` is followed by Typescript (currently Typescript 2.2) to resolve type definitions for the package.

After struggling with this, I spent some time creating a typescript boilerplate/starter project that demonstrates how to do it properly:

**https://github.com/bitjson/typescript-starter**

That project includes a lot more documentation, and [several examples](https://github.com/bitjson/typescript-starter/tree/master/examples) of how to import code from typescript projects.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: With TS 2.2 this has gotten quite a lot better. See the accepted answer.

It seems this is not really possible yet in typescript 1.8.x. But they seem to work on it via https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7156.

Also the problem is supposedly mitigated by using a jsconfig.json which should be used by VScode (see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vscode/2015/07/06/visual-studio-code-es6/). Sadly i didnt get it working yet.